# Transform an array of connected elements to a tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, diagram

Given an array of connected elements, how can I make an array of children?

```
const array = [
  {id: "dndnode_0", ...},
  {id: "dndnode_1", ...},
  {id: "dndnode_2", ...},
  {id: "dndnode_3", ...}
]
```

```
const connections = [
  {source:'dndnode_0', target:'dndnode_1'},
  {source:'dndnode_0', target:'dndnode_2'},
  {source:'dndnode_2', target:'dndnode_3'},
]
```

I am using [react-flow-renderer](https://reactflow.dev/) library BTW.
[image: user gragging & gropping elements]

I want something like this

```
const array = [
  {
    id: "dndnode_0", 
    children: [
      {id: "dndnode_1", ...},
      {id: "dndnode_2", ...}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "dndnode_2",
    children: [
      {id: "dndnode_3", ...}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Does answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a map keyed by node id, and where the corresponding values are the node objects with an additional (empty) `children` property.

Then populate those `children` properties while iterating over the connections.

Finally get the values out of that map, and optionally only keep the nodes that have children:

```js
const nodes = [
  {id: "dndnode_0" },
  {id: "dndnode_1" },
  {id: "dndnode_2" },
  {id: "dndnode_3" }
]


const connections = [
  {source:'dndnode_0', target:'dndnode_1'},
  {source:'dndnode_0', target:'dndnode_2'},
  {source:'dndnode_2', target:'dndnode_3'},
]

const map = new Map(nodes.map(node => [node.id, {...node, children: []}]));
for (const {source, target} of connections) map.get(source).children.push(target);
const tree = [...map.values()].filter(node => node.children.length);

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: This is the best solution, I just change this line

`for (const {source, target} of connections) map.get(source).children.push(target);`
with

`for (const {source, target} of connections) map.get(source).children.push(map.get(target));`  

Thank you!